# Enviar JSON com python para API laravel

Tags: php, python, laravel, api, python-requests

Estou montando uma lista com objetos para enviar via post para uma api em feita em laravel, porém não consigo converter os dados para trabalhar na API.
Em python a lista de objetos é algo tipo:

```
payload = [
    {"nome":"Flávio", "email":"teste@mail.com"},
    {"nome":"novo", "email":"novo@mail.com"}
]
```

Estou usando a biblioteca request do python para enviar:
Cód do script python

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Authorization': token
}

requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Na API com Laravel eu recebo assim:

```
public function imporUsers(Request $request)
{
    $data = ($request->getContent());
    return $data;
}
```

Mas a resposta que eu tenho é uma **Sring** igual ao **payload** q informei a cima e eu não consigo pegar os dados com um `$data[0]['nome']` por exemplo.
Tentei fazer um json_decode, mas ele da um erro falando que o parâmetro informado está errado.

Preciso transformar essa string em um array do php para acessar a chave e valor.

Comment: Tente mudar o `Content-type` para `application/json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo de envio json para o server PHP

```
data = json.dumps(
        {
            exemple:
            {
                'chave':'Valor',
                'chave':'Valor'
            }
        }
    )
```

`response = requests.post(URL_WEBSERVICE, data = data, timeout=TIMEOUT_POST, headers=headers)`

No controller no laravel

```
    public function foo(Request $request){
        $json_recebido = $request->json();
        //dd($json_recebido);
    }
```

Comment: Opa, vlw mano. Eu precisava fazer o json_dumps ao adicionar o objeto na lista.
Outro problema tbm é q meu array estava com um dado errado. Um dos valores estava retornando `NAN` e não reconhecia quando tentava fazer o json_decode.

Answer (score -1):

Faz o seguinte teste:

```
requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

Usando o parâmetro `json` na requisição, irá mudar o `Content-Type` no *header* para `application/json`.

Comment: Poderia explicar o que difere esta forma da que ele fez na pergunta?

Comment: Using the json parameter in the request will change the Content-Type in the header to application/json.

Comment: Exatamente essa informação é a que falta na sua resposta para justificar a solução :D (em português, de preferência)

Comment: Já tentei fazer assim mas não deu certo. Eu consigo enviar e receber os dados na api. Só q chega uma string e eu não consigo listar todos os objetos dentro dela